# Bean not found for topic name when using BinderAwareChannelResolver

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using BinderAwareChannelResolver to publish messages to dynamic topics.

Its throwing Failed to find MessageChannel bean with name 'topic-name'.

Comment: You provided absolutely no relevant information for this question to be answered. No sample configuration, no code snippet, no stack trace, no versions of framework used etc. . ..

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, BinderAwareChannelResolver is deprecated in the 3.0:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream#notable-deprecations

> The **BinderAwareChannelResolver** is deprecated in favor if providing `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` property. This is primarily for function-based programming model. For StreamListener it would still be required and thus will stay until we deprecate and eventually discontinue StreamListener and annotation-based programming model.

So you should use `sendto.destination` property, you have mor info in  the docs:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_stream_sendto_destination

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below. I used functional programming.

We can get beans via ApplicationContext.

I create the channel name as a string and I get the bean according to this channelName from the application context.

```
MessageChannel messageChannel = createMessageChannel(channelName);
messageChannel.send(getMessageBuilder().apply(data));

public MessageChannel createMessageChannel(String channelName) {
return (MessageChannel) applicationContext.getBean(channelName);}

public Function<Object, Message<Object>> getMessageBuilder() {
return payload -> MessageBuilder
.withPayload(payload)
.setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
.build();}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.